Encountering difficulties in TensorFlow TF-Agents
I’m looking to train a DQN for tic-tac-toe. I’ve been referring to the following resources:

tf-agents-DQN-example
tf-agemts-environments-example

Environments

Python: 3.11
TensorFlow: 2.15.0
tf-agents: 0.19.0

My tic-tac-toe environment
# coding=utf-8

"""A state-settable environment for Tic-Tac-Toe game."""

import copy

import numpy as np

from tf_agents.environments import py_environment
from tf_agents.specs import BoundedArraySpec
from tf_agents.trajectories.time_step import StepType
from tf_agents.trajectories.time_step import TimeStep


def ternary(number: np.int32):
    return np.base_repr(number, 3).zfill(9)


class TicTacToeEnvironment(py_environment.PyEnvironment):
    """A state-settable environment for Tic-Tac-Toe game.

    For MCTS/AlphaZero, we need to keep states of the environment in a node and
    later restore them once MCTS selects which node to visit. This requires
    calling into get_state() and set_state() functions.
    """
    REWARD_WIN = np.asarray(1.0, dtype=np.float32)
    REWARD_LOSS = np.asarray(-1.0, dtype=np.float32)
    REWARD_DRAW_OR_NOT_FINAL = np.asarray(0.0, dtype=np.float32)
    # A very small number such that it does not affect the value calculation.
    REWARD_ILLEGAL_MOVE = np.asarray(-0.001, dtype=np.float32)

    REWARD_WIN.setflags(write=False)
    REWARD_LOSS.setflags(write=False)
    REWARD_DRAW_OR_NOT_FINAL.setflags(write=False)

    def __init__(self, rng: np.random.RandomState = None, discount=1.0):
        """Initializes TicTacToeEnvironment.

        Args:
          rng: If a random generator is provided, the opponent will choose a random
            empty space. If None is provided, the opponent will choose the first
            empty space.
          discount: Discount for reward.
        """
        super(TicTacToeEnvironment, self).__init__(handle_auto_reset=True)
        self._rng = rng
        self._discount = np.asarray(discount, dtype=np.float32)
        self._state = None

    def action_spec(self):
        return BoundedArraySpec((), np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=8)

    def observation_spec(self):
        return BoundedArraySpec((1,), np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=3 ** 9 - 1)

    def _reset(self):
        self._state = 0

        return TimeStep(
            StepType.FIRST,
            np.asarray(0.0, dtype=np.float32),
            self._discount,
            np.asarray(self._state, dtype=np.int32)
        )

    def _legal_actions(self, state: np.int32):
        return [i for i, c in enumerate(ternary(state)) if c == '0']

    def _opponent_play(self, state: np.int32):
        actions = self._legal_actions(state)

        if not actions:
            raise RuntimeError('There is no empty space for opponent to play at.')

        if self._rng:
            i = self._rng.randint(len(actions))
        else:
            i = 0

        return actions[i]

    def get_state(self) -> TimeStep:
        # Returning an unmodifiable copy of the state.
        return copy.deepcopy(self._current_time_step)

    def set_state(self, time_step: TimeStep):
        self._current_time_step = time_step
        self._state = time_step.observation

    def _step(self, action: np.int32):
        state_t = ternary(self._state)

        if state_t[action] != '0':
            return TimeStep(
                StepType.LAST,
                TicTacToeEnvironment.REWARD_ILLEGAL_MOVE,
                self._discount,
                np.asarray(self._state, dtype=np.int32),
            )

        self._state += 3 ** action

        is_final, reward = self._check_states(self._state)

        if is_final:
            return TimeStep(StepType.LAST, reward, self._discount, np.asarray(self._state, np.int32))

        # TODO(b/152638947): handle multiple agents properly.
        # Opponent places '2' on the board.
        opponent_action = self._opponent_play(self._state)
        self._state += 3 ** opponent_action << 1

        is_final, reward = self._check_states(self._state)

        step_type = StepType.MID

        if not self._state:
            step_type = StepType.FIRST
        elif is_final:
            step_type = StepType.LAST

        return TimeStep(step_type, reward, self._discount, np.asarray(self._state, np.int32))

    def _check_states(self, state: np.int32):
        """Check if the given states are final and calculate reward.

        Args:
          state: state of the board.

        Returns:
          A tuple of (is_final, reward) where is_final means whether the states
          are final are not, and reward is the reward for stepping into the states
          The meaning of reward: 0 = not decided or draw, 1 = win, -1 = loss
        """
        state_t = ternary(state)
        states = np.array([[state_t[3 * i + j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])

        seqs = np.array([
            # each row
            states[0, :],
            states[1, :],
            states[2, :],
            # each column
            states[:, 0],
            states[:, 1],
            states[:, 2],
            # diagonal
            states[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)],
            states[(2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 2)],
        ])
        seqs = seqs.tolist()

        if ['1', '1', '1'] in seqs:
            return True, TicTacToeEnvironment.REWARD_WIN  # win

        if ['2', '2', '2'] in seqs:
            return True, TicTacToeEnvironment.REWARD_LOSS  # loss

        if '0' in states:
            # Not final
            return False, TicTacToeEnvironment.REWARD_DRAW_OR_NOT_FINAL

        return True, TicTacToeEnvironment.REWARD_DRAW_OR_NOT_FINAL  # draw


My main program
# coding=utf-8

import tensorflow as tf

from tf_agents.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
from tf_agents.drivers import dynamic_step_driver
from tf_agents.networks import q_network
from tf_agents.replay_buffers import tf_uniform_replay_buffer
from tf_agents.utils import common

from tic_tac_toe_enviornment import TicTacToeEnvironment

num_iterations = 20000  # @param {type:"integer"}

initial_collect_steps = 100  # @param {type:"integer"}
collect_steps_per_iteration = 1  # @param {type:"integer"}
replay_buffer_max_length = 100000  # @param {type:"integer"}

batch_size = 64  # @param {type:"integer"}
learning_rate = 1e-3  # @param {type:"number"}
log_interval = 200  # @param {type:"integer"}

num_eval_episodes = 10  # @param {type:"integer"}
eval_interval = 1000  # @param {type:"integer"}


def compute_avg_return(environment, policy, num_episodes=10):
    total_return = 0.0

    for _ in range(num_episodes):
        time_step = environment.reset()
        episode_return = 0.0

        while not time_step.is_last():
            action_step = policy.action(time_step)
            time_step = environment.step(action_step.action)
            episode_return += time_step.reward

        total_return += episode_return

    avg_return = total_return / num_episodes

    return avg_return.numpy()[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_py_env = TicTacToeEnvironment()
    eval_py_env = TicTacToeEnvironment()

    train_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(train_py_env)
    eval_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(eval_py_env)

    fc_layer_params = (100, 50)
    action_tensor_spec = train_env.action_spec()
    num_actions = action_tensor_spec.maximum - action_tensor_spec.minimum + 1

    q_net = q_network.QNetwork(
        train_env.time_step_spec().observation,
        train_env.action_spec(),
        fc_layer_params=fc_layer_params,
    )

    agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
        train_env.time_step_spec(),
        train_env.action_spec(),
        q_network=q_net,
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
        train_step_counter=tf.Variable(0))
    agent.initialize()

    replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
        agent.collect_data_spec,
        batch_size=train_env.batch_size)

    # (Optional) Optimize by wrapping some of the code in a graph using TF function.
    agent.train = common.function(agent.train)

    # Reset the train step.
    agent.train_step_counter.assign(0)

    # Evaluate the agent's policy once before training.
    avg_return = compute_avg_return(eval_env, agent.policy, num_eval_episodes)
    returns = [avg_return]

    # Reset the environment.
    time_step = train_py_env.reset()

    # Add an observer that adds to the replay buffer:
    replay_observer = [replay_buffer.add_batch]

    collect_steps_per_iteration = 10
    collect_op = dynamic_step_driver.DynamicStepDriver(
        train_env,
        agent.collect_policy,
        observers=replay_observer,
        num_steps=collect_steps_per_iteration).run()


Encountering error
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'QNetwork' (type QNetwork).

Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (50,)

Call arguments received by layer 'QNetwork' (type QNetwork):
  • observation=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=False

Does anyone know what caused this error?

The error you're encountering indicates a mismatch between the expected input shape by your QNetwork and the actual shape of the observation passed to it. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the input shape passed to your QNetwork matches the observation spec of your environment. In your case, since the observation spec is (1,), you should reshape or expand the observation to match the expected input shape of your QNetwork.
When initializing QNetwork, make sure to pass the correct observation spec from your environment

@Priya T Thank you for reply. After modifying the observation spec to (), it performs correctly.
